# A stubborn fixed DIV inside a 100% DIV

Tags: html, css

*This must be the most frequently occurring issue in my life!*

I have to position a fixed DIV (800px) inside a 100% DIV and as always it works fine in everything but IE. I have tried the old "text-align" trick but nothing this time, I just can't get it to work.

If you want to inspect the actual page its www.chunkydesign.com and any answer would be greatly appreciated.

**Here is the HTML** *(CSS Below)*

```
<body>

    <div id="navContainer">

        <div id="navTopSpacer"></div>

        <div id="navMain">

            <div id="navContent">

                <div id="navLogo"></div>

                <div id="navLinks">

                    <h1>SERVICES ABOUT PORTFOLIO CONTACT</h1>

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

        <div id="navBotSpacer"></div>

    </div>

</body>
```

**The devil code itself:**

body {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

## navContainer{

```
width: 100%;
height: 110px;
```

}

## navTopSpacer {

```
width: 100%;
height: 12px;
background-image: url('../images/core/nav_topspacer.jpg');
```

}

## navMain {

```
width: 100%;
height: 88px;
background-image: url('../images/core/nav_main.jpg');
```

}

## navContent {

```
text-align: center;
width: 800px;
height: 88px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

}

## navLogo {

```
float: left;
width: 164px;
height: 88px;
background-image: url('../images/core/logo.png');
background-position: 0px 20px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

}

## navLinks {

```
float: right;
width: 400px;
height: 88px;
```

}

## navLinks h1 {

```
font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
text-align: right;
font-size: 13px;
color: #FE9900;
font-weight: 600;
padding-top: 40px;
word-spacing: 15px;
letter-spacing: 1px;
margin: 0px;
```

}

## navBotSpacer {

```
width: 100%;
height: 10px;
background-image: url('../images/core/nav_botspacer.jpg');
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By leaving a comment above your doctype you're making IE go into quirks mode, which makes rendering a nightmare.

Remove the comment and have NO text, spaces or anything above your doctype declaration.

Comment: Thanks so much Paul, I never knew that commenting above the Doctype activated quirks mode, makes sense now as its the first thing the browser interprets. All seems to work fine now. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this markup:

```
<div id='header'>
    <div class='center'>
        <div id='logo'><h1><a href='' title=''></a></h1></div>
        <ul id='navigation'>
            <li>SERVICES</li>
            <li>ABOUT</li>
            <li>PORTFOLIO</li>
            <li>CONTACT</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

And styling like this:

```
#header{
background:#cae1e9;
border-top:12px solid #7ebdce;
border-bottom:10px solid #a8d2de;
height:88px;
}
.center{
width:800px;
margin:auto;
}
```

Then just maybe float logo to the left and float navigation to the right or do whatever you want. But this kind of makup is much easier to understand and maybe see where is the error.

Combine that with the answer Paul gave you and i think that's it.

Comment: Thanks for the advice GaVrA, together with Paul's advice its fixed the problem. Cheers. :-)